# How to remove the rows from a spark dataframe which matches the regex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Input dataframe

```
import spark.implicits._

val ds = Seq((1,"play Framwork"),
  (2,"Spark framework"),
  (3,"spring framework")).toDF("id","subject")
```

I could use any **regex** and the my function should `remove those rows` from the dataframe that matches the regex token .

Suppose my **regex** is **^play.*** then my function should remove first row and produces the following result .

```
val exp = Seq((2,"Spark framework"),
  (3,"spring framework")).toDF("id","subject")
```

I was thinking to use a **function** like below

```
def clearValueUsingRegex(dataFrame: DataFrame, token: String, columnsToBeUpdated: List[String]) = {
Logger.debug(s"Inside clearValueUsingRegex : token :$token , columnsToBeUpdated : $columnsToBeUpdated")
if (isValidRegex(token)) {
  columnsToBeUpdated.foldLeft(dataFrame) {
    (dataset, columnName) =>
      dataset.withColumn(columnName, regexp_replace(col(columnName), token, ""))
  }
} else {
  throw new NotValidRegularExpression(s"$token is not valid regex.")
}
```

}

But problem with this function is that it only replaces the particular cell value , not removing the complete row as my expected result .

Comment: What's wrong with `select * from df where subject not like '%play%'`?

Comment: No my intention is to remove the rows that matches a regex . It is the feature i required , token can't be a simple  string , instead a valid regular expression !
@philantrovert

Comment: Note that you cannot update a dataframe in spark. You can only transform one dataframe into another: E.g. `ds.filter(row => (! row.getString(1).matches("^play.*")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter function.

```
df.filter($"columnName" rlike "^play.*")
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html